# How to show Login Page after Logged in

Tags: php, magento, redirect, authentication, account

How to show Log in Page after Logged in

After user Logged when user type url /customer/account/login/

Magento Will Redirect to /customer/account/ not show or load /customer/account/login/

i will try to When user open url /customer/account/login/ this session is destroy and login to new user

but my code are in log in page but they not load

How i can Disable Auto redirect for this

PS. i try to turn System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Login Options  to  no but it not work

Comment: pls post you code for understanding.. your description is not clear...

Comment: i'm not sure about code i put
'
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
 
session_start(); //Start the current session
session_destroy(); //Destroy it! So we are logged out now

}' in login.phtml but this page but not load when i type 
www.myweb.com/index.php/customer/account/login/

they are script and redirect to www.myweb.com/index.php/customer/account/

i try to change in AccountController but i don't know where are code for this problem

Comment: you are starting and ending the sessions in the consequent lines... so the session is not set... as session is not set they redirect...

Comment: i can do it now thank you for Interests my problem

i try to edit in loginAction in AccountController on core\Mage\Customer\controllers folder 

and i can do it

Comment: Does that make any sense to logout by typing `/customer/account/login/`  in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change in account controller in core magento, You just need to do the following
1) Edit the class file Mage_Customer_AccountController
2) Go the function loginAction
3) Comment the following lines

if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()){$this->_redirect('*/*/');return;}

By doing this, you are editting the magento core. Otherwise you might need to create a custom module and  rewrite the AccountController class which is more better.